# Running Fluid Hello World Example Error Out

Tags: fluid-framework

I'm trying to run Fluid Hello World Example, after going through the steps and running the application the web browser error out with the following log message:

`POST http://localhost:3000/documents/tinylicious 400 (Bad Request)` with response body is 502.

Did I miss any step?

Update:

Running on Windows 10 1809 (1763.1397)

Console Output:

```
@fluid-example/hello-world@0.1.0 start C:\Users\****\Documents\Workspace\FluidHelloWorld
> concurrently "npm:start:server" "npm:start:client"

[start:server]
[start:server] > @fluid-example/hello-world@0.1.0 start:server C:\Users\****\Documents\Workspace\FluidHelloWorld
[start:server] > tinylicious
[start:server]
[start:client]
[start:client] > @fluid-example/hello-world@0.1.0 start:client C:\Users\****\Documents\Workspace\FluidHelloWorld
[start:client] > webpack-dev-server --open
[start:client]
[start:server] info: Listening on port 3000 {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-09-11T16:02:56.224Z"}
[start:client] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
[start:client] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
[start:client] i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\KISA01\Documents\Workspace\FluidHelloWorld
[start:client] i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
[start:client] i ｢wdm｣: Hash: 15f0e0aa78bd7f0ce32e
[start:client] Version: webpack 4.44.1
[start:client] Time: 11959ms
[start:client] Built at: 09/11/2020 12:03:10 PM
[start:client]                       Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
[start:client] app.52afa0dcefa1c58ec9c3.js   7.84 MiB     app  [emitted] [immutable]  app
[start:client]                  index.html  667 bytes          [emitted]
[start:client] Entrypoint app = app.52afa0dcefa1c58ec9c3.js
[start:client] [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.ts 40 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/@fluidframework/aqueduct/lib/index.js] 925 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/@fluidframework/get-tinylicious-container/lib/index.js] 180 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 4.29 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.91 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {app} [built]
[start:client] [./src/app.ts] 3.3 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./src/containerCode.ts] 1.03 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client] [./src/view.ts] 1.41 KiB {app} [built]
[start:client]     + 658 hidden modules
[start:client] Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
[start:client]      1 asset
[start:client]     Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
[start:client]     [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 913 bytes {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
[start:client] i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[start:server] info: OPTIONS /documents/tinylicious 204 3.718 ms - 0 {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-09-11T16:03:11.686Z"}
[start:server] info: POST /documents/tinylicious 400 180.004 ms - 3 {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2020-09-11T16:03:11.869Z"}
```

Comment: Hi Sarthak!  Could you please share what OS you're running on, and also confirm that you're not using port 3000 for anything else?  Also if you could share your console output from `npm start` would be helpful.

Comment: HI Tyler! Just updated the question with information you required. I can confirm that there is nothing running other than Fluid Services on port 3000.

Comment: @SarthakKilledar, did you make any modifications to the example itself? Can you attempt a re-clone to see if that works. It looks like both the Server and Client are correctly running but the server is getting a request it does not like 400 usually means you're asking for a document that hasn't been created.

Comment: @SkylerJokiel Hey! So basically, I ran the application on my personal computer again over the weekend, and I could run it with no errors. Most probably it's because of company proxy or firewall thing that was causing the issue.